# Just Date or Time

Tags: c#, datetime, date, time

I'm just wondering ..

I have and object like this

```
public class Entry{

public DateTime? Date { get; set;} // This is just Date

public DateTime? StartTime { get; set; } //This is just Time

public TimeSpan Duration { get; set; } //Time spent on entry

}
```

Is there a more appropriate type than DateTime or better strategy to handling just Time and Date? Without the pain of having to add a DateTime.MinDate() to all my Start and End Times?

--- update ---

1 - I like to be able to request if Date or StartTime is Null seperartly on the Entry object.

2 - Entry should allow the user to input Duration without indication of date. Even a default date like DateTime.MinDate() seems like a poor design. (This is why i choose TimeSpan not Start and EndTime)

Comment: What happens when your EndTime is in the next day?

Comment: Youre right Chris bad scenario. In the above example i would strike out endtime and only have Date, StartTime and Duration. Good point

Comment: @BBorg: In that case why not ditch your `Date` property altogether and have `StartTime` represent date *and* time. After all, that's what `DateTime` is for!

Comment: @Luke, Because i want to be able to ask if either entry is null .. the easy way ..Entry.StartTime == null || Entry.Date == null

Comment: @BBorg: You're allowing the user interface (being able to determine if a date is specified AND a time) to drive your business and/or data layers. You can store the date and time separately in the user interface, but I would recommend keeping them together in the back. You'll be better off in the long run.

Comment: @Adam I do not agree. Especially since this code does not yet have a UI. Entry's design is more based on the way we want to work(code) with this particular domain item in our businesslayer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't split up the date and time components where you store the data. You can provide properties to extract those if you like:

```
public class Entry {

   public DateTime StartPoint { get; set; }
   public TimeSpan Duration { get; set; }

   public DateTime StartDate { get { return StartPoint.Date; } }
   public TimeSpan StartTime { get { return StartPoint.TimeOfDay; } }
   public DateTime EndPoint { get { return StartPoint + Duration; } }
   public DateTime EndDate { get { return EndPoint.Date; } }
   public TimeSpan EndTime { get { return EndPoint.TimeOfDay; } }

}
```

Update:
If you want to have null values for date and time, you can add properties for that without having to split the date and time:

```
public class Entry{

   private DateTime _startPoint;

   public bool HasStartDate { get; private set; }
   public bool HasStartTime { get; private set; }
   public TimeSpan Duration { get; private set; }

   private void EnsureStartDate() {
      if (!HasStartDate) throw new ApplicationException("Start date is null.");
   }

   private void EnsureStartTime() {
      if (!HasStartTime) throw new ApplicationException("Start time is null.");
   }

   public DateTime StartPoint { get {
      EnsureStartDate();
      EnsureStartTime();
      return _startPoint;
   } }

   public DateTime StartDate { get {
      EnsureStartDate();
      return _startPoint.Date;
   } }

   public TimeSpan StartTime { get {
      EnsureStartTime();
      return _startPoint.TimeOfDay;
   } }

   public DateTime EndPoint { get { return StartPoint + Duration; } }

   public DateTime EndDate { get { return EndPoint.Date; } }

   public TimeSpan EndTime { get { return EndPoint.TimeOfDay; } }

   public Entry(DateTime startPoint, TimeSpan duration)
     : this (startPoint, true, true, duration) {}

   public Entry(TimeSpan duration)
     : this(DateTime.MinValue, false, false, duration) {}

   public Entry(DateTime startPoint, bool hasStartDate, bool hasStartTime, TimeSpan duration) {
      _startPoint = startPoint;
      HasStartDate = hasStartDate;
      HasStartTime = hasStartTime;
      Duration = duration;
   }

}
```

Comment: @Guffa I dont see how i could easily check if Date and Time are null seperately?

Comment: @BBorg: As you added that requirement after I answered, I added an update above.

Comment: @Guffa,, nice, I'm gonna test this a bit but i do think this will work well, TY

Answer (score 6):

You could use a [`TimeSpan`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.aspx) for your `StartTime` and `EndTime` properties. That's what the [`DateTime.TimeOfDay`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.timeofday.aspx) property returns.

There's also the [`DateTime.Date`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.date.aspx) property which returns a `DateTime` with the time element set to midnight.

Having said that, I would probably recommend ditching your `Date` property altogether and storing full `DateTime`s (ie, date *and* time) in your `StartTime` and `EndTime` properties.

Comment: I would suggest the same thing. You don't need the Date property. Just have the StartTime and EndTime contain the date info.

Comment: @Meta-Knight; in this particular case ,, the use case allows the user only to input Timespent without indication of the date or time. Which then in a later use-case is added, but not always.

Comment: @Luke Problem with ditching Date altogether is, I will unable to check if Time was set or not. Since 00:00:00 is also a valid starttime

Comment: @BBorg: Is your object actually in a useful state when the date or time is null, or do you just need to know for validation purposes etc in the UI?

Comment: @Luke the state is valid. Gaffa seems to have nailed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You're far better off leaving your references as `DateTime`s. If you only store the time, then you have issues when your `Entry` spans more than a 24-hour period. Store them as `DateTime`s as you have them now, and apply whatever formatting is necessary to represent just the time portion to your end-user.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to compliment [Guffa's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1340996/just-date-or-time/1341113#1341113) with two more best practices:

1. Store all of your dates as UTC in the database.
2. Avoid System.DateTime and [favor System.DateTimeOffset](http://weblogs.asp.net/okloeten/archive/2008/12/18/6795009.aspx).

   1. SQL Server 2008’s datetimeoffset type is the equivalent of DateTimeOffset.

Comment: @Jim G - Im happy about the answers also .. but I fail to see how i would easily check if Date was set or not (Date != null) seperatly from time (Time != null) if i merge to two properties?